# One month rails - pins_controller.rb (NameError in PinsController#new)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rubygems, associations

I am following along through the OMR course and can't seem to debug this error:

```
Started GET "/pins/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-28 09:06:35 -0400
Processing by PinsController#new as HTML
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 2  ORDER BY   "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms

NameError (uninitialized constant User::Pin):app/controllers/pins_controller.rb:15:in `new'


Rendered /Users/antonioortiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/actionpack  4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (0.7ms)
Rendered /Users/antonioortiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.6ms)
Rendered /Users/antonioortiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered /Users/antonioortiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (18.1ms)
```

And this from the browser:
    NameError in PinsController#new
    uninitialized constant User::Pin

```
Extracted source (around line #15):

def new
  @pin = current_user.pins.build
end

def edit
```

Added models

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user

   has_attached_file :image, styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>"}
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
   # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :pins
end
```

Addded routes.rb

```
Pinteresting::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :pins

  devise_for :users
  root "pages#home"
  get "about" => "pages#about"

end
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you post your models?

Comment: Does the `User` model has `has_many :pins` in it?

Comment: Can you post your `routes.rb` file?

Comment: I added the routes.rb file...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you associations are setup right in the models.

User `has_many` pins and Pin `belongs_to` User.

Comment: How come you can't use has_one if you only wanted the user to be able to create one pin? I had a similar error and changed my has_one to has_many, and it works now.

Comment: @Ken did you read the questions completely? he said `has_many`

Answer (score 0):

**Inherited Model**

The error basically states that Rails is trying to find an inherited model - the type which would be present if you had namespaced them:

```
#app/models/users/pin.rb
Class User::Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
   ...
end
```

The issue here is that you don't want this; you want to access the `Pin` model itself.

--

**Solution**

I think the problem is the way you're using `build`

I don't think `build` would be an issue, but I'd imagine you're using it to populate a `form_for` object. If this is the case, the problem will likely be that `Rails` will try and extract the model name from the object you've created

The issue is your object is built as an associative relation, which will likely cause Rails to become confused. I'd say a better thing to test is this:

```
#app/controllers/pins_controller.rb
Class PinsController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @pin = Pin.new #-> you can assign a user later
   end
end
```

Try that and see if it works